# Typescript save class in Record?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-class

There seems to be a problem when I try to give the abastarct class value to the Record with Typescript.

```
abstract class PurchaseBundleMoveStrategy {
    purchaseBundle:PurchaseBundle;

    move() {
    }
}

class BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy implements PurchaseBundleMoveStrategy {
    constructor(public purchaseBundle:PurchaseBundle) {
    }
    move() {
    }
}

class TimelineBundleMoveStrategy extends BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy {
    move() {
    }
}

class TimeBundleMoveStrategy extends BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy {
    move() {}
}

class RangeDayMoveStrategy extends BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy {
    move() {}
}

export const PurchaseBundleMoveStrategies: Record<BuyPageType, BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy> = {
    DAY_RANGE: RangeDayMoveStrategy, //err
    RESERVATION_NORMAL: BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy, /err
    SHOPPING_MALL: BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy, //err
    SURVEY: BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy, //err
    TIMELINE: TimelineBundleMoveStrategy, //err
    TIME_MALL: TimeBundleMoveStrategy //err
}
```

Error
 `typeof RangeDayMoveStrategy' is missing the following properties from type 'PurchaseBundleMoveStrategy': purchaseBundle, move`

What is the above error telling me?
And how to save my classes in Record ?

---add BuyPageType is just a enum

Comment: `BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy` describes the type of the object that you get when you instantiate the class. To get the type of the actual class, use `typeof BasePurchaseBundleMoveStrategy` instead

Comment: @AlexChashin Thanks problem solved by your answer.